# GeoTools JTS: Snap a Point to a polygon (equivalent to PostGis ST_ClosestPoint)

Tags: geotools, snapping, jts-topology-suite

I'm using GeoTools JTS libraries in Java and I want to find the nearest point inside polygon shape to some single target location. This is exactly what in PostGis [ST_ClosestPoint](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html) does.

I found [this article](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jts/snap.html) discussing "Snap a Point to a Line".

So trivial solution will be:

```
-Dump polygon to lines
-Snap a Point for each above Line
-Calculate the distance between the point and "the snapped" point
-Take the one with minimum distance
```

How can I achieve my requirement in GeoTools in more "elegant" way?

EDIT:

Actually I'm not sure if the link to snap a point doing exactly what ST_Closest because I don't understand how it's actually extracting the closest point...

Comment: Convert polygon into MultiLineString and it will be enough to take just one closest point.

Comment: @user30184 You mean with the method in above documentation link? I think this could be an 'answer'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JTS's DistanceOP#nearestPoints might be an easy way. I have not tested it.

http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/operation/distance/DistanceOp.html#nearestPoints%28com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry,%20com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry%29

> Compute the the nearest points of two geometries. The points are presented in the same order as the input Geometries.

Comment: Hi, is there any better performance alternative for DistanceOp? I have fixed set of polygons (let's say 100) and random points (let's say 100.000). I need to find min distance between every point and polygons.

Comment: Use a spatial database like PostGIS

Comment: thanks for your advice, but I have some environment limitations unfortunately, I won't be able to do it.

Comment: Then use some spatial index like rtree or something (I am not developing Java anymore, so I do not know).